# How to improve the speed on wifi using ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04?

Tags: wireless

I use a dual boot computer. Everything is fine on Window but on Ubuntu:

My wifi got to be really fast but since few weeks, it was really slow than I reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 but it didn't fix the problem. So I tried 12.04 LTS , it didn't fix it either.

Ubuntu detects the Wifi like good quality one when I'm not connected to it, but when I'm connected to it the quality dropped.

I tried all six solutions : [Speed Up Slow WiFi Connection In Ubuntu 13.04](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/)

except the `wicd` because I was not able to start `wicd` after installed it.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BtNyd3gt

Comment: Please don't include the answer (solution) in your question. Instead, post the answer as an answer or mark an existing answer as correct. That is how this site works.

Comment: Yeah but I wasn't aloud to post an answer to my own question .... I must wait 8 hours ... so I will not post the solution I found like I CAN'T

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Then I recommend changing the channel in the router to 1 or 11.

Also please set your wireless settings in network manager to match the images below

[image: wireless settings].[image: wireless settings]

Comment: When I run sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm  FATAL: Module iwldvm not found.

Comment: That is okay continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: "Then I recommend changing the channel in the router to 1 or 11" I dont know how to do that, I did everything else , the connection is still slow

Comment: It's "semi-public" routers , I don't access to it, but the connection is slow with all routers

Comment: Please do: `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and paste the contents of the file to pastebin. Then run the script again and paste to pastebin so we can see if the changes you made were saved.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MkTTwdyE

Comment: http://pastebin.com/05rqCss1

Comment: Some of the information looks a lot better. Please run internet speed tests and see how fast it is now.  How are you determining the speed now?

Comment: If I use http://www.speedtest.net/    ..... it's 6 mbps , it's around 20 on window,  and the wifi connection is at the bottom if I look at top right of my screen

Comment: sometimes my connection is strong but during 4-5 seconds ... and after is weak again

Comment: I found that I install WICD help a little , no with speedtest it's more around 10mbps but, it's still nothing compare to window 45 mbps ....

Comment: it's seem to be really depending how much percentage I catched when it's around 90% the speed is around 16mbps , when is around 60% the speed is 5 mbps

Comment: Exactly you have a weak signal in the information you posted. The stronger the signal the faster the speed but also many other things affect speed, I suspect channel interference is an issue. Tomorrow I will look and see if setting another driver parameter might help a little.