# Wireless connected but internet not working or extremely slow. Ubuntu 12.04 on Samsung N210

Tags: 12.04, wireless, samsung

I've finally got Ubuntu installed but the wireless internet connection either doesn't work or runs extremely slowly. I also have Windows 7 and the internet works, but only because I updated my wirelss driver (it was exactly the same as it is now on Ubuntu prior to that). I know there are many similar postings on here but they seem either too complex for me to understand or simply give me error messages when I try the given solutions. If anyone can help, please just tell me what I need to do in order to give you the information you might need, bearing in mind I'm not an advanced user. Thanks in advance!

The information requested from lspci:

Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8192] (rev 01)

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
 sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
 sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
 sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

thread taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354534/how-to-improve-the-speed-on-wifi-using-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04) **but first read that article then try it**

Comment: I went through the thread but nothing has helped. I couldn't access dropbox via Terminal, presumably because of my internet troubles.